# About application testing on Java Application

Tags: java, testing

I am doing load test on my server and using JMeter. Do I have any difference choice??

How can I do integration test and How can I do it? Is there any tool?
I know the concept but I dont know how to apply on my project.

My company required me to do a report on load test. Is there any standard on testing? Such as need to use 50 people access and plot the graph of response time?

Sorry I am new to System analyst.

Comment: ...What *kind* of testing are you doing? Unit tests?  Integration tests?  Automated tests?  We need specifics here.

Comment: "Can JUnit do tests?"  ...Probably?

Comment: any suggestion on three of them?

Comment: I don't see a request for code so the reason for the "On-Hold" seems really iffy.  As for Jeff, you are in a hard position being hired for a job that you aren't prepared for.  Consider looking for books on the topic (so you can read them at home) and scour the web for information and examples.  If you want to keep this job I suggest you do your best while at work and spend every minute you're not at work (or asleep) trying to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Junit is a framework to support test cases it doesn't provide the tests themselves.

Load testing tends to be specific to the application so you can use JUnit to support that
but you will have to write the tests yourself.

you could look at [jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [LoadUI](http://www.loadui.org/)